Is there a way to edit non-custom term attributes?
I have a custom post type (FAQs), taxonomy (FAQ Categories) and everytime I want to create one it appears all the same name, slug, parent, description fields. I was wondering... If there is a possibility I could override, for example, the 'Name' input bottom label?


After building countless custom plugin functions to manage taxonomy meta, I've found ACF plugin to be so much easier. Not selling anything here, just saying sometimes it's worth paying for a good premium plugin and ACF is excellent. You can edit custom meta details for each taxonomy and also customize the main "name" field using filters.

There's a filter for taxonomy labels, taxonomy_labels_{$taxonomy} (the {$taxonomy} should be replaced with your custom taxonomy name) that allows you to filter pretty much all of it.
Example:
// Assuming your custom taxonomy is named 'faq_category'. Adjust as needed.
add_filter( 'taxonomy_labels_faq_category', 'wpse626542_taxonomy_labels' );
/**
 * Filters the taxonomy labels.
 *
 * @param  object $labels The taxonomy labels.
 * @return object         The filtered labels.
 */
function wpse426542_taxonomy_labels( $labels ) {
    // Changes the label on the Name field.
    $labels->name_field_description = __( 'My Custom Name Description', 'my-plugin' );
    // Change any other labels you want, and then...
    return $labels;
} 

A full list of the labels can be found in the get_taxonomy_labels() docs.
